# does removing all non-numeric characters effectively escape data?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

I use this function to strip all non-numeric from a field before writing to a MYSQL dB:

```
function remove_non_numeric($inputtext) {return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$inputtext);
```

Does this effectively escape the input data to prevent SQL Injection?  I could wrap this function in `mysql_real_escape_string`, but thought that might be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Assumption is the mother of all *bleep* when it comes to sql injection. Wrap it in mysql_real_escape_string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It does not escape the data, but it is indeed an example of an [OWASP](http://owasp.org) recommended approach.

By removing all but numerics from the input you are effectively protecting against SQL-Injection by implementing a [White list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet#White_List_Input_Validation).  There is no amount of paranoia that can make the resulting string (in *this* specific case) into an effective SQL Injection payload.

**However**, code ages, and changes and is misunderstood as it's inherited by new developers.  So the bottom line, the correct advice, the end all and be all - is to actively prevent against SQL Injection with one or more of the following 3 steps. In this order.   Ever. Single. Time.

1. Use a safe database API. (prepared statements or parametrized queries for example)
2. Use db specific escaping or escaping routines (`mysql_real_escape_string` falls into this category).
3. [White list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet#White_List_Input_Validation) the domain of acceptable input values.  (Your proposed numeric solution falls into this category)

`mysql_real_escape_string` is not the answer for all anti-sql-injection. It's not even the most robust method, but it works.  Stripping all but numerics is white listing the safe values and is also a sound idea - however, neither are as good as using a safe API.